# Landscape mode not working in App release (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I need help, I am using flutter to make App will have 3 interfaces 1- Mobile application (portrait) 2- Tablet/iPad (portrait) 3- Tablet/iPad (Landscape)... during debugging stage this was working perfectly till I made the app release... now the App is detecting the Portrait mode of the tablet but does not change to landscape (it seems that the App is not detecting the landscape mode)...here is a copy from my code

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'constants.dart';
import 'home_page.dart';

class ContactUs extends StatefulWidget {
  ContactUs({required this.contactUsHeader, Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  String contactUsHeader;

  @override
  _ContactUsState createState() => _ContactUsState(contactUsHeader);
}

enum ResultField { FeedBack, Subject }

class _ContactUsState extends State<ContactUs> {
  _ContactUsState(this.contactUsHeader);
  final String contactUsHeader;
  final _fieldFeedBack = TextEditingController();
  final _fieldSubject = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode focusFeedBack = FocusNode();
  FocusNode focusSubject = FocusNode();

  List unchangedFields = [ResultField.FeedBack, ResultField.Subject];

  String valueFeedBack = '';
  String valueSubject = '';
  bool userSetFeedBack = false;
  bool userSetSubject = false;

//=====These parameters to make responsive font size
  double SonyZRWidth = 360;
  double SonyZRHeight = 592;

  void listenerFieldFeedBack() {
    if (focusFeedBack.hasFocus) {
      try {
        valueFeedBack = _fieldFeedBack.text;
        userSetFeedBack = true;
      } catch (e) {}

      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void listenerFieldSubject() {
    if (focusSubject.hasFocus) {
      try {
        valueSubject = _fieldSubject.text;
        userSetSubject = true;
      } catch (e) {}

      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // _fieldFeedBack.addListener(listenerFieldFeedBack);
    // _fieldSubject.addListener(listenerFieldSubject);
  }

  void feedBackEmail() {
    String encodeQueryParameters(Map<String, String> params) {
      return params.entries
          .map((e) =>
              '${Uri.encodeComponent(e.key)}=${Uri.encodeComponent(e.value)}')
          .join('&');
    }

    final Uri params = Uri(
      scheme: 'mailto',
      path: 'talotech.engtools@gmail.com',
      query: encodeQueryParameters(<String, String>{
        'subject': valueSubject,
        'body': valueFeedBack,
      }),
    );
    launch(params.toString());
  }

//===== This to activate the calculate button
  bool activateSend() {
    bool isActivated;
    if (_fieldSubject.text != '' && _fieldFeedBack.text != '') {
      isActivated = true;
    } else {
      isActivated = false;
    }
    return isActivated;
  }

//===== This is to show the text of the missing fields
  String missingFields() {
    String tostText = '';
    if (_fieldFeedBack.text == '' && _fieldSubject.text == '') {
      tostText = 'Please enter the subject & your thoughts';
    } else if (_fieldFeedBack.text == '') {
      tostText = 'It seems that you did not share you thoughts with Us';
    } else if (_fieldSubject.text == '') {
      tostText = 'What about the subject.. please fill in the subject field';
    }
    return tostText;
  }

  void toastisMissing() =>
      Platform.isIOS ? cupertinoAlertIsMissing() : toastIsMissingAndroid();

  /// This is to determine between toast massage for android or Cupertino Alert Dialod for IOS.
//====== this is the imported toast massage for android
  void toastIsMissingAndroid() {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: missingFields(),
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
    );
  }

//====== this is the Cupertino alert Dialog for IOS
  void cupertinoAlertIsMissing() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (ctx) {
          return CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: Text(missingFields()),
            actions: [
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                child: const Text('Noted'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double scaleFactorWidth = 360 / MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double scaleFactorHeight = 592 / MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

//=====This is the scale factor for mobiles
    double scaleFactorScreenMobile = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width +
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) /
        (SonyZRWidth + SonyZRHeight);
    double scaleFactorTabletLandscape = scaleFactorScreenMobile - 0.5;

    //==== This is to determine the shortest side of the device to determine if iPad/Tablet or mobile phone
//==== 552 was selected based on my tablet Lenovo TAB 2 A7, physical number were extracted from the App in debug mode
    final double shortestSide = MediaQuery.of(context).size.shortestSide;
    final bool useMobileLayout = shortestSide < 552;

//====== This to force the mobile device to be in Portrait mode only ========
//===========================================================================
    if (useMobileLayout) {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    }

    double mobilePadding() {
      double valuePadding;
      if (useMobileLayout == true) {
        valuePadding = 20;
      } else {
        valuePadding = 60;
      }
      return valuePadding;
    }

    Widget buildContactUsTabletLandscape() {
      return Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 0.4 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: 1 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  // image: DecorationImage(
                  //   image: AssetImage('images/header.png'),
                  //   fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  // ),
                  ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      border: Border.all(color: kAppGrey),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                          spreadRadius: 1,
                          blurRadius: 3,
                          offset:
                              const Offset(0, 1), // changes position of shadow
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    height: useMobileLayout
                        ? 0.75 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
                        : 0.75 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    width: 0.90 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: 60, right: 60, bottom: 10.0, top: 8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Image.asset('images/email2.png'),
                              const SizedBox(width: 15),
                              Text(
                                'Contact Us',
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: kAppGreyFont,
                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                textScaleFactor: useMobileLayout
                                    ? scaleFactorScreenMobile
                                    : scaleFactorTabletLandscape + 0.8,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 15),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                contactUsHeader,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  wordSpacing: 1,
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                textScaleFactor: useMobileLayout
                                    ? scaleFactorScreenMobile
                                    : scaleFactorTabletLandscape + 0.8,
                              ),
                              FloatingActionButton(
                                backgroundColor: activateSend() == true
                                    ? kAppGreen
                                    : kAppGreen.withOpacity(0.4),
                                child: Transform.rotate(
                                  angle: -30 * pi / 180,
                                  child: const Icon(
                                    Icons.send,
                                    size: 35,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                elevation: 8,
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    if (activateSend() == true) {
                                      feedBackEmail();
                                      Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) {
                                            return const HomePage();
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    } else {
                                      toastisMissing();
                                    }
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 15),
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Subject',
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                textScaleFactor: useMobileLayout
                                    ? scaleFactorScreenMobile
                                    : scaleFactorTabletLandscape + 0.8,
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 10),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 50,
                                child: Center(
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    focusNode: focusSubject,
                                    controller: _fieldSubject,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 17 *
                                            (useMobileLayout
                                                ? scaleFactorScreenMobile - 0.2
                                                : scaleFactorTabletLandscape)),
                                    onTap: () {},
                                    onChanged: (_) => listenerFieldSubject(),
                                    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
                                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                      labelText: 'Subject',
                                      hintText: 'Subject...',
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Content',
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                            textScaleFactor: useMobileLayout
                                ? scaleFactorScreenMobile
                                : scaleFactorTabletLandscape + 0.8,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          TextFormField(
                            focusNode: focusFeedBack,
                            controller: _fieldFeedBack,
                            onTap: () {
                              activateSend() ? feedBackEmail() : null;
                            },
                            onChanged: (_) => listenerFieldFeedBack(),
                            maxLines: 3,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 17 *
                                    (useMobileLayout
                                        ? scaleFactorScreenMobile - 0.2
                                        : scaleFactorTabletLandscape)),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                            textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              labelText: 'My Message',
                              hintText: 'Please write here...',
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

//====this is for mobile & tablet portrait mode
    Widget buildMobilePortrait() {
      return Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 0.4 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: 1 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  // image: DecorationImage(
                  //   image: AssetImage('images/header.png'),
                  //   fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  // ),
                  ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      border: Border.all(color: kAppGrey),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                          spreadRadius: 1,
                          blurRadius: 3,
                          offset:
                              const Offset(0, 1), // changes position of shadow
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    height: useMobileLayout
                        ? 0.75 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
                        : 0.75 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    width: 0.90 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          left: mobilePadding(),
                          right: mobilePadding(),
                          bottom: 10.0,
                          top: 8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Image.asset('images/email2.png'),
                              const SizedBox(width: 15),
                              Text(
                                'Contact Us',
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: kAppGreyFont,
                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                textScaleFactor: useMobileLayout
                                    ? scaleFactorScreenMobile
                                    : scaleFactorTabletLandscape + 0.8,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 15),
                          Text(
                            contactUsHeader,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              wordSpacing: 1,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            textScaleFactor: useMobileLayout
                                ? scaleFactorScreenMobile
                                : scaleFactorTabletLandscape + 0.8,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 15),
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Subject',
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                textScaleFactor: useMobileLayout
                                    ? scaleFactorScreenMobile
                                    : scaleFactorTabletLandscape + 0.8,
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 10),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 50,
                                child: Center(
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    focusNode: focusSubject,
                                    controller: _fieldSubject,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 17 *
                                            (useMobileLayout
                                                ? scaleFactorScreenMobile - 0.2
                                                : scaleFactorTabletLandscape)),
                                    onTap: () {},
                                    onChanged: (_) => listenerFieldSubject(),
                                    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
                                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                      labelText: 'Subject',
                                      hintText: 'Subject...',
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Content',
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                                textScaleFactor: useMobileLayout
                                    ? scaleFactorScreenMobile
                                    : scaleFactorTabletLandscape + 0.8,
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 10),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 150,
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  focusNode: focusFeedBack,
                                  controller: _fieldFeedBack,
                                  onTap: () {
                                    activateSend() ? feedBackEmail() : null;
                                  },
                                  onChanged: (_) => listenerFieldFeedBack(),
                                  maxLines: 5,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 17 *
                                          (useMobileLayout
                                              ? scaleFactorScreenMobile - 0.2
                                              : scaleFactorTabletLandscape)),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.top,
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                    labelText: 'My Message',
                                    hintText: 'Please write here...',
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 0.08 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                            width: 0.82 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            child: TextButton.icon(
                              onPressed: () {
                                if (activateSend() == true) {
                                  feedBackEmail();
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) {
                                        return const HomePage();
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  );
                                } else {
                                  toastisMissing();
                                }
                              },
                              label: Text(
                                'Send',
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  letterSpacing: 1,
                                ),
                                textScaleFactor: useMobileLayout
                                    ? scaleFactorScreenMobile
                                    : scaleFactorTabletLandscape + 0.8,
                              ),
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.email_rounded,
                                size: 30 *
                                    (useMobileLayout
                                        ? scaleFactorScreenMobile - 0.2
                                        : scaleFactorTabletLandscape),
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              style: ButtonStyle(
                                elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(5),
                                backgroundColor:
                                    MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                        activateSend() == true
                                            ? kAppGreen
                                            : kAppGreen.withOpacity(0.4)),
                                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                    RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                    // side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kAppGrey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: kAppGrey,
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color: kAppGreyFont, //change your color here
        ),
        title: Text(
          'Contact Us',
          style: kAppBarTitleHeader(),
          textScaleFactor: useMobileLayout
              ? scaleFactorScreenMobile
              : scaleFactorTabletLandscape,
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: OrientationBuilder(
          builder: (context, orientation) =>
              orientation == Orientation.landscape
//================= This is for LandScape mode for iPad/Tablets
                  ? buildContactUsTabletLandscape()
//================= This is for Portrait mode for iPad/Tablets
                  : buildMobilePortrait(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

also, I tried to use  MediaQuery instead of OrientationBuilder

```
  child: useMobileLayout
      ? buildMixingMobile()
      : MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait
          ? buildMixingTabletPortrait()
          : buildMixingTabletLandscape(),
),
```

I don't understand what is the reason for this problem & I can't solve it... please help

Comment: Are you running it on ipad? Or android tablet?

Comment: Hi, I am running now for the test Android Tablet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the solution for the issue, the main cause is `SystemChrome` since as per my code I wanted the mobile screen to be in the portrait mode always so I added

```
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    }
```

and for some how the app started to implement the same even in the tablet landscape mode... so I made some adjustment in the App code such as

```
        child: !useMobileLayout
            ? MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait
                ? buildMixingTabletPortrait()
                : buildMixingTabletLandscape()
            : buildMixingMobile(scaleFactorScreenMobile),
      ),
```

& then I added the condition to change the orientation inside the mobile mode widget as the following

```
  Widget buildMixingMobile(double scaleFactorScreenMobile) {
//====This to make the mobile screen always in the portrait orientation
    final isPortrait =
        MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape;

    if (isPortrait) {
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    }
//=======================================================================
    return Align(
```

Now the App is working as I wanted

Answer (score 0):

In your release android manifest please remove this line

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will try it as soon as I finish duty... thanks in advanced

Comment: Hi, I don't have in my Android manifest this line...

Comment: android:screenOrientation="unspecified" add this to manifest and try once

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I found the main issue & now it is solved....Thanks again